# Помогите с ошибкой в делфи

Tags: delphi, pascal

Пытаюсь сделать чтобы функция брала слова из массива и проверяла их наличие в строке, в чем ошибка помогите?
ТЕПЕРЬ ОШИБКА ВОТ ТУТ В VAR, ошибку показывает на скобках при обьявлении массива
Вот код:

```
procedure TForm1.N22Click(Sender: TObject);
var
id, i, s: integer;
stroka: string;
n, k: integer;
a : array[1..5] of String[10]=('VAR','END','BEGIN','FUNCTION','IF');
begin
ListView1.Clear;
id:= 0;
for i := 0 to SynEdit1.Lines.Count-1 do begin

{ do if не должно быть на одной строке }
if Pos('do if', SynEdit1.Lines[i]) <> 0 then begin
    ListView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
    ListView1.Items.Add;
    id:=id+1;
    ListView1.Items[id-1].Caption:=IntToStr(id);
    ListView1.Items[id-1].SubItems.Add('[Строка: '+IntToStr(i+1)+'] - do if не должен быть на одной строке');
    ListView1.Items.EndUpdate;
end;

     { зарезервированные слова - не работает}

if Pos(a[i], SynEdit1.Lines[i]) <> 0 then begin
    ListView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  ListView1.Items.Add;
  id:=id+1;
  ListView1.Items[id-1].Caption:=IntToStr(id);
  ListView1.Items[id-1].SubItems.Add('[Строка: '+IntToStr(i+1)+'] - зарезервированные слова не должны заглавными буквами');
  ListView1.Items.EndUpdate;
end;

end;
```

Comment: ссылка на картинку битая. В любом случае, неработающий код должен быть _непосредственно_ в вопросе. Отредактировать вопрос можно нажав кнопку [edit] под ним

Comment: Насколько я помню в делфи можно объявлять переменные только в блоке var в начле функии, а не в середине.

Comment: судя по картинке - есть попытка объявить переменную a прямо по среди кода. А так вроде как нельзя (раньше в делфи так точно нельзя было писать).

Comment: В var тоже обьявлена, a: array[1..5] of string[10];

Comment: а что тогда вы хотите сделать в средине кода с этой переменной? компилятор иногда нужные вещи пишет! можно почитать!

Comment: Видимо вы должны инициализировать массив в серкии var:
var
  a: array[0..10] of integer = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11);

Comment: Мне нужно именно массив состоящий из слов, чтобы он брал слова из него и проверял их наличие в строке

Comment: Занесите вот это a : array[1..5] of String[10]=('VAR','END','BEGIN','FUNCTION','IF'); в блок var, поменяйте вот эту стркоу на Pos(a[i], SynEdit1.Lines[i])

Comment: @Unick, и добавить еще один вложенный цикл по элементам массива, потому что переменная i принимает значение номера строки из исходного текста и строк может быть больше чем элементов в массиве, да и не логично выходит

Comment: вопрос не решен, появилась ошибка в var

Comment: @OLGA Учите синтаксис языка Delphi, раз уж вы решили на нём писать. В секции `var` нельзя делать какие-либо инициализации переменных.

Comment: выше в комментарии мне так посоветовали, что к чему?

Comment: @OLGA Советчик сам не знает, что он советует и, очевидно, Delphi он не знает.

Comment: Что посоветуете вы?

Comment: @OLGA Учить базовый синтаксис языка, а конкретно - [инициализацию массивов](http://delphiru.ru/other/426-declare-and-init-stat-array).

Comment: а просто сказать, как исправить ошибку нельзя? а то как то бред

Comment: вам уже вроде сказали, что ошибка в том, что в секции `var` нельзя инициализировать массивы. выхода два: 1) инициализировать в теле функции 2) объявить массив в секции `const`, там можно задать значения.

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TForm1.N22Click(Sender: TObject);
var
...
const
  a: array [1..5] of string = ('VAR','END','BEGIN','FUNCTION','IF');
begin
```

Инициализацию переменных в секции `var` можно делать только если это глобальная секция в модуле, а не в функции или процедуре.